# Notation for subring of quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, notation

Let $S$ be a subring and $I$ an ideal of the ring $R$. What is the appropriate notation for the subring of $R/I$ given by $\{ s + I: s \in S \}$? Is it appropriate to write $S/I$ even though $I$ is not necessarily an ideal in $S$ or should one stick to the more technically correct $(S + I)/I$ or $S/(S \cap I)$?

Comment: I don't see the necessity of a special notation, unless you have a notation for $R/I$ such as $R'$ or $\bar R$, in which case you may denote it $S'$ or $\bar S$.  All this should explicited to avoid any confusion with the isomorphic quotient ring $S/S\cap I$.

Comment: If you're just looking for notation to describe a subring: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1925867/what-is-the-notation-for-saying-s-is-a-subring-of-r