# What is the notation for saying $S$ is a subring of $R$?

Tags: ring-theory, notation

I can't find any. For saying $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ we have notation but it seems none exists for subrings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is correct. There is a notation for ideal, yet no notation for subring, as far as I know.
One just writes: "Let $S \subset R$ be a subring."

Anyway, also the notation for subgroup, ideal and alike is not used all that much. "Let $H\subset G$  be a subgroup." Is what I see all the time.

Comment: I don't think 'none exists for subrings' is correct (cf. my answer)

Comment: This is  not a dedicated notation for a subring. I also do not think that it is self explanatory. You'd need to say in addition that $R$ and $S$ are rings.

Comment: Yes I agree. I explain this in my answer. Moreover the question made no mention of the notation being dedicated.

Comment: Alright so $\subset $ is also a notation for subring.

Comment: Of course you would need to say they are rings... What kind of mathematics would just begin by talking about two symbols without first explaining what they are?

Comment: No $\subset$ means 'subset'. Not even sub-object.

Comment: One *can* write: "Let $G$ be a group. Consider $H \lt G$ and $K \lhd G$." To express that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ without saying that $H$ and $K$ are groups or anything (since those are established notations to express this, one may or may still recall the meaning of the notation, but anyway they are established notations for this). Likewise, for Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Consider $I \lhd R$. To express that $I$ is an ideal. You cannot do this with your notation. The questions seeks an analogues for those notations. My claim is they do not exist.

Comment: I agree with this answer. I've never seen special notation for it.

Answer (score 5):

I have used and seen $S\leq R$ to say that $S$ is a substructure of $R$.

Answer (score 5):

As you asked for the notation, I read this as how subrings are identified in the literature so I looked up the definitions for subrings in a few well known books. I checked the books on Algebra by Artin, Dummit & Foote, Hungerford, Jacobson, Lang, van der Waerden, where notation for a subring seems to be nonexistent, i.e., "is a subring" is as good as it gets, at least in their definition of what a subring is.

Fraleigh in *A First Course in Algebra*, p.173 holds off *explicitly* defining any notation, but states:

> ... In fact, let us say here once and for all that if we have a set, together with a certain type of *algebraic structure* (group, ring, field, integral domain, vector space, and so on), then any subset of this set, together with the natural induced algebraic structure *that yields an algebraic structure of the same type,* is a *substructure*. If $K$ and $L$ are both structures, we shall let $K\le L$ denote that $K$ is a substructure of $L$ and $K<L$ denote that $K\leq L$ but $K\neq L$.

Then in Rotman's *Modern Algebra*, he defines a subring then gives the following on p.119:

> **Notation.** In contrast to the usage $H \leq G$ for a subgroup, the tradition in ring theory is to write $S \subseteq R$ for a subring. We shall also write $S  \subsetneq R$ to denote a *proper* subring; that is, $S \subseteq R$ and $S \neq R$.

So it seems fair to say $S\subseteq R$, and $S\leq R$ can be safely used in place of any explicit notation reserved for subrings.

Answer (score 0):

If $S$ is a subring of $R$ we write $S\hookrightarrow R$. The hooked arrow means 'monomorphism', which encapsulates the idea of $S$ being isomorphic to a sub-object of $R$ which is in this case a sub*ring*.

**EDIT**

After the discussion in quid's answer I will explain this a little.

The symbol '$\subset$' means 'subset'. The symbol '$\hookrightarrow$' means 'subobject'. Hence the latter can be used to denote a subgroup, a subring, a sub(topological/metric/&c.)space and indeed even a subset.

Comment: A subring is usually an actual subset. The question is not "If $S$ is a subring of $R$ we can write $S\hookrightarrow R$." but "If we  write $S\hookrightarrow R$, is it understood as $S$ is a subring of $R$." The former is true, the latter more doubtful. You *can* also use $\subset$ to denote subgroups etc. This is done all the time. It is just that $\subset$ does not imply it is a subgroup.

Comment: @quid Actually I disagree with most of this. In fact, I claim it would be universally understood that $S\hookrightarrow R$ means '$S$ is a sub-object of $R$', since this is exactly the definition of $\hookrightarrow$. Of course a subring is a subset, but a subset is not a subring.

Comment: Moreover, the claim that $\subset$ can denote subgroup is false. Even in a context such as 'let $H\subset G$ be a subgroup', it still means 'subset' (its saying: "let H be a subset of G that is also a subgroup"). If we write $S\hookrightarrow R$ it will ALWAYS be understood that $S$ is *isomorphic* to a subring of $R$, which is the same thing as $S$ being a subring of $R$.

Comment: It is definitely not the same thing. For one thing $R$ could have multiple subrings that are isomorphic to $S$. So consider $S= \mathbb{R}[X]$ and $R= \mathbb{R}[Y_1, Y_2]$. According to your definition $S$ is a subring of $R$, since clearly there is a monomorphism from $S$ to $R$. But I do not think $S$ will usually be considered as a subring. You'd need to decide on one of the several possible embeddings to make it a subring. Maybe you meant to say this, i.e. a subring is a ring plus the embedding, but this is not what you said. I also would continue to disagree.

Comment: For example, I do not think that many will agree that $\{ \begin{pmatrix}a & -b \\  b & a   \end{pmatrix}  \colon a , b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ *is* a subring of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Both examples are subrings, the second perhaps slightly less obvious. The fact that $k[X]$ and $k[Y]$ are the same ring is, I think, clear.

Comment: Then please tell me is $X-Y_1=0$ or $X - Y_2=0$?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any standard notation for "is a subring of."  If $S, R$ are rings, and one writes $S \subseteq R$ (literally, $S$ is a subset of $R$), then it is tacitly assumed that the operations on $S$ making it into a ring are restricted from those of $R$.  It follows from here that $0_S = 0_R$, but if $S$ and $R$ are rings with identity, it is not necessarily true that $1_S = 1_R$.  Many authors tacitly assume this as well when they speak of subrings.

Comment: Even if $S$ inherits the operations of addition and multiplication from $R$ it is not necessarily a subring of $R$. For example, $\{0,1,2,3\}\subset \mathbb{Z}$ is not a subring.

Comment: Right, $S$ is assumed to be a ring to begin with.